# Local Drupal website connecting to a remote database

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal.  I want to run my Drupal website locally and connect directly to the remote database, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I have MAMP installed on the Mac and I have all the files in the htdocs folder.  It looks like I just need to change the settings.php file to match my remote database, but I'm unsure what I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

I guest you look at this drupal.org HowTo that step by step guides you through creating the database and what you need to change before running the Install program.

https://www.drupal.org/node/66187

Also check the comments on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to adjust your settings file (`/sites/default.settings.php`), database configuration. Watch out, usually there is a different ("external") host for accessing database from out of server. I think that it can be set per database user does it has privileges to access database from outer server or not. Maybe there's some special user for that.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any extra setup or configuration. Just make sure that

1. You are connected to the remote database (usually goes in `sites/default/settings.php`).
2. The database host allows remote connections.